# Digit sum of a prime number

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let  be a positive integer and
 = () be the digit sum of  such that
 + 1 ≡ 0 (mod 2).
Is it that if  is prime then  is also prime?

e.g. =47(prime)-> =4+7=11 (prime)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not necessarily, but it takes a while to see this, because
you're not allowing $q$ to be a multiple of $2$, and it cannot be
a multiple of $3$ (other than $3$ itself) because then the same
would be true of $p$.  So the smallest candidate for $q$ is $25$,
which happens for the first time at $p=997$.